# Showing $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}x^a=ax^{a-1}$ with out using logarithm/exponential differential laws

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Given $a \in\mathbb{R}$, let us choose two sequences $\{p_n\}$ and $\{q_n\}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $p_n<p_{n+1}<a<q_{n+1}<q_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}{|q_n-p_n|}=0$.

I have to prove that

1. for each $\epsilon>0$ and  $n \in\mathbb{N}$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $p_n - \epsilon<\frac {x^a-1} {x-1}<q_n + \epsilon$ for all $x$ with $0<|x-1|<\delta$
2. $x^a$ is differentiable on $(0,\infty)$ and
   $f'(x)=\frac{a}{x} x^a$ for all $x\in$$(0,\infty)$.

I found out that $\lim_{n \to \infty}{q_n}=\lim_{n \to \infty}{p_n}=x^a$.

I tried to show that for $f(x)=x^a$, $f'(1)=a$ and $f'(x)=ax^{a-1}$ simply using differential rules for exponential and logarithmic functions.
However, I am required to NOT use differential rules for exponential and logarithmic functions, so I guess I should depend on $\epsilon-\delta$ argument.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the definition of $x^a$ that you are working with?

Comment: Are you allowed to expand $(x+\epsilon)^a$ by [Newton's generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem)?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we are given the derivative for integer powers, proved for instance using the Binomial Theorem. Suppose also that $x^q=y^p$ for some nonzero integers $p,q$ and $y$ is a continuous function of $x$. We then have

$qx^{q-1}=py^{p-1}(dy/dx)$

$qx^q=py^p(x/y)(dy/dx)$

Canceling $q^x$ on the left with the equal quantity $y^p$ on the right and solving for the derivative gives

$dy/dx=(p/q)(y/x)$

which **extends the power rule to rational exponents.**

We would use a limit process on the exponent to pass over to real exponents.